# Ajax POST request Error(500) for Flask on Heroku

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, heroku, flask

I've deployed to Heroku a flask controller with a proper index.html file that successfully loads (the page is deployed and reachable).

While uploading a file, the JavaScript code creates an Ajax POST Request but get Error 500 in return.

This is the controller

```
import GeoLocationExtractor
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/geolocations', methods=['POST'])
def myfunc():
    text = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    locations = GeoLocationExtractor.tag_locations_from_text(text)
    return locations


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is the function that triggers once you upload a file:

```
 function openFile(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            var text = reader.result;
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "In Progress.";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/geolocations",
                dataType: "text",
                data: text,
                success: function (text) {
                    addMarkers(text)
                },
                // dataType: "text"
            });

            <!--addMarkers(text)-->
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    };
```